# Making a Scrollable table and insert inner table border

Tags: html, css

How can I?

Given the html coding below, how can I 1.) Lock the first row (table headers) from scrolling and 2.) Have an inner table border of 1px solid #cccccc

Thanks for all your help!

Jay

Style Coding:

```
<style type="text/css">
div#data_container {
width: 800px;
height: 75px;
overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;

}
table#data_tbl {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table#data_tbl td {
  border: 0px;
}
table#data_tbl tr:first-child td { 
color: #235A81;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#cdcdcd");
}
</style>
```

Body:

```
<!-- START OF DATA CONTAINER -->
<div id="data_container">

    <table id="data_tbl">
        <td>File Number</td>
        <td>Date Received</td>
        <td>Request Type</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <tr>
            <td>12345678</td>
            <td>08/01/2013</td>
            <td>Billing</td>
            <td>Joe Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>09876543</td>
            <td>09/01/2013</td>
            <td>Technical</td>
            <td>Nancy Edwards</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11223344</td>
            <td>10/01/2013</td>
            <td>Operations</td>
            <td>Jill White</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>45678931</td>
            <td>12/01/2013</td>
            <td>Billing</td>
            <td>Michael Burns</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>85239975</td>
            <td>09/01/2013</td>
            <td>Support</td>
            <td>Debbie Stewart</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>55667788</td>
            <td>11/01/2013</td>
            <td>Administrative</td>
            <td>David Adams</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- END OF DATA CONTAINER -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Style table for borders:

```
table {
position: relative;
}
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: the table th styling code doesn't work. It just bolds the titles and centers them.

Comment: The table border just adds a border around it. I've put a border around it already using a div. I guess it would be no table table border around it (maybe white?) and only a cell border.

Comment: I created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3xX2/) for you. I believe this is what you expected to be.

Comment: Deleted half answer by accident. Sorry... Everything is on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use 3rd party plugin. check this out: http://dlippman.imathas.com/projects/tablescroller.php or try datatables.net

Answer (score 0):

You can set `style="overflow:hidden"` on `th` tag when box appears. It will lock mouse scroll or use `position:fixed` on a box.